# How to implement Haystack java toolkit library in my java code?

Tags: java, iot

I have a requirement to develop an IoT based Java application and I have been told to implement [Haystack java toolkit](https://bitbucket.org/brianfrank/haystack-java/src/default/). But I am unaware that how I would use Haystack tag library to convert data from diverse devices into standard tags using java code.

Where should I start from and how?

I have also tried going through the [documentation page](https://project-haystack.org/) but what I found is just tag details rather than java sample code to convert it.

I would also like you to help me with the simple java code snippet.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is too broad for this page. You should explicitly try to show what you already have tried, and what exactly your problem is (e.g. your Java code not finding any Haystack classes). I recommend reading [ask] first.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same requirement of using Haystack as a library. But after exploring the Haystack documentation, I found that it cannot be used as a library.

Instead, we have to clone Haystack Java application from here (https://bitbucket.org/brianfrank/haystack-java/src/default/) and we need to enhance the same application as per our requirement.

After posting in Haystack Forum, I came to know the Haystack java toolkit can be build and embed into whatever kind of application you have.

Please refer this query in Haystack Forum for the same. 
https://project-haystack.org/forum/topic/722

Answer (score 0):

The Haystack Java toolkit has moved to [github](https://github.com/skyfoundry/haystack-java), and is being supported there.

One can start by cloning it, and opening haystack-java/index.html.